# How do I show alphabetical ordering across all search result pages?

Tags: 2007, search, search-results

I am working on MOSS 2007 and trying to order the results returned by the people search alphabetically by name across all pages. Currently the results are sorted alphabetically on each page rather than across **all** pages.

I have read the way to order the results is by passing parameters to the search via the URL query string rather than by the XSL.

I have tried passing the following to the URL by [using this page](http://snahta.blogspot.com/2008/12/search-url-query-string-parameters.html) as a reference:

> k=Department%3A%22Legal%22&start1=52&v1=LastName

But the results are still sorted by last name on each page rather than across all pages. This looks like a common problem with out of the box people search.

Can anyone advise a possible way to achieve sorting across all pages?